# Android Facebook OpenGraph error

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

developers, I'm trying to share a victory in my game with ShareOpenGraph but I obtain a transparent clickable screen and Facebook don't do anything. I try with the example code of the developer's guide but do the same. This is my code and the only error I can see.

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderxxxxxxxx"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Code:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
                .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
                .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
                .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
                .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
                .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
                .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
                .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
                .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
                .build();
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                .setActionType("fitness.runs")
                .putObject("fitness:course", object)
                .build();
        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
                .setAction(action)
                .build();
        ShareDialog.show(a,content);
```

Error:

```
05-29 10:46:19.760 3498-3498/com.viridesoft.artpuzzle W/com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker: Unexpected activity pause without a matching activity resume. Logging data may be incorrect. Make sure you call activateApp from your Application's onCreate method
05-29 10:46:19.786 20218-20218/? D/AppStateLogger: Activity com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity changed state to Created
05-29 10:46:19.812 20218-20307/? E/X.0UC: RuntimeException while executing runnable X.0Xh@79325c with executor X.0Uz@72e4469
                                          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                              at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(:66160)
                                              at com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.ComposerConfiguration.<init>(:120263)
                                              at com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.ComposerConfiguration$Builder.a(:590139)
                                              at X.Hek.a(:2204609)
                                              at X.0Xh.run(:90937)
                                              at X.0Uz.execute(:72617)
                                              at X.01e.a(:5892)
                                              at X.0UC.executeListener(:71135)
                                              at X.0UC.complete(:71132)
                                              at X.0UC.setFuture(:71265)
                                              at X.1dG.a(:255631)
                                              at X.1XY.run(:244317)
                                              at X.1pF.run(:311679)
                                              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                              at X.0Z6.run(:93236)
                                              at X.0VK.run(:73244)
                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                              at X.0ZB.run(:93430)
                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```